# Styling of XML through XSLT

Tags: xml, arrays, xslt

I have a XSLT document that spits out the contents of an XML document like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">         
    <xsl:template match="/">    
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>CL Results</title>
        <link href="xml.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>34 Participants</h1>
        <table>      
        <xsl:for-each select="results/person">      
            <tr>
                <th colspan="16">
                    <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            mailto:<xsl:value-of select="@epost" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                    </a>
                </th>        
            </tr>      
            <xsl:for-each select="stage">
                <tr>                            
                    <xsl:for-each select="team">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>                         
                    </xsl:for-each>         
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
     </body>
     </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I wish to give the td elements that contain certain teams different styling.

So I need an array containing for instance "Barcelona", "Arsenal" and "Lyon" (plus many more), and whenever the team element of the XML contains either of these, I want the team to be displayed in e.g. red colour.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this part of your xsl transform :

```
<xsl:for-each select="team">
    <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>                         
</xsl:for-each>
```

You can use conditionals :

```
<xsl:for-each select="team">
    <xsl:variable name="color">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Barcelona'">
          red
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test=". = 'Arsenal'">
          blue
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          yellow
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <td style="color:{$color}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </td>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: That sure does the trick, thanks, but is it a way to reduce the amount of tests by using an array with the teams?

Comment: @maralbjo An array not. But a mapping between each team and it's color would be indeed helpful. Then you would use the name of the team as key and of course the value would be the color.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off matching with templates.

```
<xsl:for-each select="team">
    <td><xsl:apply-templates /></td>                         
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template match="team">
   <div class="normal"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="team[@name='Barelona' | @name='Lyon' | @name='Arsenal']">
   <div class="red"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></div>
</xsl:template>
```

Or another option is to keep an XML file relative to the XSL and reference it using the document() function.  So if you had a file called redTeams.xml that looked like this:

```
<redTeams>
    <team name="Barcelona" />
    <team name="Arsenal" />
    <team name="Lyon" />
</redTeams>
```

You could reference it with something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="team[@name = document('redTeams.xml')/redTeams/team/@name]">
   <div class="red"><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></div>
</xsl:template>
```

Or if you need to do it programmatically, you could also pass a variable into the XSL using xsl:param and match against that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<td class="{team}">
```

and then use a CSS stylesheet to define the appropriate colour for each team. It's best to use XSLT to get the structural arrangement of the HTML right, and CSS for the detailed styling of each HTML element.

(You can generate the CSS stylesheets using XSLT as well if you want, though I've rarely seen it done in practice.)